# HTML&GRAILS - urls text is not displayed as hyperlink

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have the following gsp code:

```
<p class="common-text ">${direction?.description?.toHtml()?.decodeHTML()}</p>
```

`direction?.description` is a text which the user entered in some input field. This text could includes website URLs like `Visit my new site www.example.com`

How can I verified if some of the text contains a URL, and if so display it as hyperlink?

The text above should be transformed to something like:

`Visit my new site <a href="www.example.com"> www.example.com </a>`

Comment: Please explain better, you want `description` displayed as the text of an html link?

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do this.

### Server side with a Grails taglib

You could create a [custom Grails taglib](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#taglibs) that look for URLs in your text and replace with `<a>` tags when needed. It could be used like this:

```
<myTagLib:replaceUrls>${direction?.description}</myTagLib:replaceUrls>
```

### Client side with javascript

You can use a javascript library to search URLs in strings and then auto replace them with the proper hyperlink. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) for more information about this techinque.

Comment: @lifeisfoo- it is. I should display it in <p> tags no <a>..... some of the text is regular text

Comment: I can't understand your problem: did you mean that some of the possible values of `direction?.description` could be URLs?