# Groovy- how to recognize a url in the text and display it as hyperlink

Tags: grails, groovy, hyperlink, gsp

I tried encodeAsHTML() as the following:

```
<p class="common-textmb-30">${direction?.description?.encodeAsHTML()}</p>
```

where "direction?.description" is a text which the user enterd in some input.

It didn't detect the url.

Comment: give an example of `direction?.description`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML&GRAILS - urls text is not displayed as hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370492/htmlgrails-urls-text-is-not-displayed-as-hyperlink)

Comment: @injecteer- for example "our new site is http://www.newsite.com"

Comment: why do you think, it SHOULD detect the ilnks?

Comment: @ injecteer- it should in groovy

Comment: no, it should not and does not

Comment: it does.... I use it several times

Comment: @SaritRotshild you've already opened [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370662/3340702). Please don't open the same the question multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

`encodeAsHTML` just escapes reserved HTML symbols (such as `<`) to an entity reference (`&lt;` for the previous example), so that the text is not interpreted by the browser, but presented as it originally was.

You can detect if an `String` is a valid using the java class `java.net.URL`:

```
boolean isURL(String someString) {
   try { 
      new URL(someString)
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      false
   }
}
```

but is not something you would put in the view. You can therefore use a [taglib](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tag%20Libraries/Usage.html):

```
class ViewFormatterTagLib {

   static namespace = 'viewFormatter'
   def renderAsLinkIfPossible = { attrs ->
      String text = attrs.text
      out << (
         isURL(text) ? "<a href='${text}'>${text}</a>" : text
      )
   }

   private boolean isURL(String someString) {
       try { 
          new URL(someString)
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          false
       }
    }
}
```

and in the view just do:

```
<p class="common-textmb-30">
   <viewFormatter:renderAsLinkIfPossible text="${direction?.description"/>
</p>
```

Comment: @Deigot- how can I import to the tagLib this class. p.s I write in Grails . Should I write import java.net.URL?

Comment: @Deigot- I got an error -No signature of method: com.threebaysover.EventTagLib.isUrl() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [http://www.one.co.il/Article/15-16/1,1,3,0/256641.html?ref=hp]

Comment: There's a typo. `isUrl(text)` should be `isURL(text)`. I don't know where the EventTagLib.isUrl() is coming from since the example taglib is named ViewFormatterTagLib. So I'm assuming you named it something else.